# Wordpress file uploading error

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using visual Form Builder plugin to allow the user to upload files. It works fine for normal files but when i upload the video file of large size approx 25MB then it ends up with the connection reset and the PHP warning of max upload size exceeds the limit.
But then page becomes ir-responsive and does not loads until i clear everything from my browser.

Comment: What you want to achieve ?

Comment: What happens when i clear the browser data ?

Comment: what is the link between the browser data and page, page does not loads untill i clear the browser data after error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to increase the website max upload size you should do it in wp_config.php and php.ini it's possible to add it in .htaccess too but that's not the best idea, go into php.ini and wp_config.php and search for upload then increase 25 to whatever you want it to be. If it doesn't work then I probably missed something and you can make additional search for increasing upload size in wp or php.